# rectForRowAtIndexPath getting wrong frame when using scrollToRowAtIndexPath using uiTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In a Cell button click action I am calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath for visible cells.After that

```
CGRect rect = [myLoadTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

rect is not returning correct value if i call scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

Below is my code for reference:

```
- (IBAction)morebtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
    {
     CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero          toView:myLoadTableView];
    selectedIndexPath = [myLoadTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    [myLoadTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                               atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                       animated:YES];

        [myLoadTableView reloadData];
    CGRect rect = [myLoadTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: What about if you use `selectedIndexPath = [[myLoadTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];`?

Comment: if i won't use scrollToRowAtIndexPath I am getting frame correctly so issue is not with the index path.

Comment: What is the effect of scrolling to a row that is already visible?

Comment: for already visible cell getting correctly

Comment: getting what?  If its already visible then there is no need to scroll.

Comment: ok...iam getting frame correctly...